# auto fail to deduce correct return type

Tags: c++, c++14

I have declared a function which returns `auto` type of a `shared_ptr` of  parameterized template class. In my case compiler complains me about incomplete type if I add "else" condition. With same function signature it works fine with one condition. Any elegant solution to make the compiler happy.

```
auto getCustomerDataSource(ptree const &node){
   const auto dataSource = node.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.Type");
   const auto sourceString = node.get<std::string>("SourceString");
   if (dataSource == "File") {
     return std::make_shared<CustomerData<CFileSource>>(sourceString);
   } else if (dataSource == "DataBase") {
     return std::make_shared<CustomerData<CDatabaseSource>>(sourceString);
   }
 }
```

Comment: What happens if neither `if` is true?

Comment: what would you write as return type if you didnt use `auto` ? ie what did you expect to be deduced for the return type?

Comment: `auto` does not mean "can be anything", it is just a shortcut that prevents you from writing the return type explicitly

Comment: This is very hard to anticipate what should be concrete type if I don't provide auto as return type. 
 Concrete return type is  based on the actual parameter passed to template class.

Comment: is there any relation between `CustomerData<CFileSource>` and `CustomerData<CDatabaseSource>` (other than being instantiations of the same template) ? If not, only `variant` or similar you can use, though you should rather fix your design to make the method return one concrete type

Comment: please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show explicitely the code that compiles and the code that does not compile. Don't describe your code, but show it.

Comment: CFileSource & CDatabaseSource are two possible algorithms that user can pick to build CustomerData object. You can consider getCustomerDataSource as factory method which returns shared_ptr of CustomerData<> based on the parameter passed.

Answer (score 14):

Your code violates the following rule from the C++ Standard [[dcl.spec.auto.8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#8):

> If a function with a declared return type that contains a placeholder type has **multiple non-discarded `return` statements**, the return type is deduced for each such `return` statement. **If the type deduced is not the same in each deduction, the program is ill-formed**.

---

> `CFileSource` & `CDatabaseSource` are two possible algorithms that user can pick one to build `CustomerData` object.

A problem is that you are trying to use a static polymorphism (templates) for something that is decided at runtime. A better solution would therefore be to provide your *algorithms* as polymorphic classes with a common base. Then, you might make a pointer to base being a member variable of `CustomerData`, which won't need to be a template any longer.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!!  a too generalized class with run time polymorphic is possible solution to resolve my problem.
Yes my attempt is to achieve static polymorphic for template. I find decltype keyword which somewhat resolve this issue but it also didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

When `auto` is used, the deduced return type for the function *must* be the same for every possible path the program may take. Here your function has 3 different possible return types:

1. first `if` body is executed: `std::shared_ptr<CustomerData<CFileSource>>`
2. second `if` body is executed: `std::shared_ptr<CustomerData<CDatabaseSoruce>>`
3. neither is executed: `void`

This is not valid.

Answer (score 4):

> CFileSource & CDatabaseSource are two possible algorithms that user
>   can pick one to build CustomerData object. You can consider
>   getCustomerDataSource as factory method which returns shared_ptr of
>   CustomerData<> based on the parameter passed.

It appears that your misunderstanding is the following: There is no relation between two instantiations of the same template other than that they are instantiations of the same template.

Consider:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo{};

??? bar(bool x) {
    if (x) return Foo<int>();
    return Foo<double>();
}
```

There is no type you could put in place of `???` because `Foo<int>` and `Foo<double>` are not related by any means. They are instantations of the same tempalte, but thats all.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
struct Moo_base {};

template <typename T>
struct Moo : Foo_base {};
```

Because now `Moo<int>` and `Moo<double>` can both be passed around via a `std::shared_ptr<Moo_base>`.